# IONIC TextEncoder not being recognized, but if you rebuild the app it work?

Tags: build, ionic3

I am working on an IONIC 3 application. In the app I am using TextEncoder to encode some strings using UTF8.

Now if I build the application I get he following error message:
"Cannot find name 'TextEncoder'."

However if I rebuild the app this error message disappears. - basically i add a space any where in the source code and save which triggers the rebuild and it works like a charm -.

The problem now is that I could not do the same thing when trying to generate an apk. I am still getting this error message and can't get rid of it.

could anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

yours sincerely.

Answer (score 1):

Found out what the problem is:

First I have to install the text-encoder module like this:

**npm i text-encoding**

Next I have to include the encoder and decoder like this:

**import { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } from 'text-encoding';**

and everything worked perfectly.